# Building iOS app through the error in mixpanel

Tags: angular, ionic2

I get the following message while building my iOS app:

```
BUILD FAILED

The following build commands failed:

CompileC build/CareShield.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CareShield.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/UIImage+MPAverageColor.o CareShield/Plugins/cordova-plugin-mixpanel/Mixpanel/UIImage+MPAverageColor.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

But it's working in Android. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Try this**

**Changed the Xcode compile language default.**

my build still fails, got a compile error at UIImage+MPAverageColor.m

if your got this error: "variable-sized object may not be initialized" from char colorIndices[kNumberOfHexColors] = {0};.
this is caused by compiler using a wrong C dialect (C99 for example).
to fix:

```
open your project in xcode.
goto build settings tab.
scroll down to "apple llvm 8.0 - language".
set "C language dialect" to be default.
```

please check **README.md** file

Comment: can't find this is Xcode 8. specifically 8.3.1 - looks like a bug https://github.com/samzilverberg/cordova-mixpanel-plugin/issues/58